# Why my active rigid body objects not collide with passive rigid body objects

Tags: armature, rigid-body-simulation

Why my active rigid body objects not collide with passive rigid body objects?
I used rigid body for the hair and I want it to collide with the body,so I make some collider.I set the collider as passive and the hair as active,but they do noy collide.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure your hair will be inlcuded in the rigid body simulation stack even if you apply a rigid body to the empties. Might want to look into the molecular addon as it calculates collisions for particles, etc